# Objective-c: recursive call of viewDidLoad after addSubview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am working in Xcode 4.5.2.
I have the following problem:
When i make projects from non-empty projects - that is the views are initialised from the storyboard, sometimes when i add the code

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
b.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:b];
```

to the viewDidLoad method it is recursively called again after the addSubview method call and sometimes (bless the sky) it doesn't.
Can anyone tell me what's the problem and how to solve it?
My gratitude.

Comment: Can you provide the method where this is called (or at least more code, ideally the whole method)? The sample you've given is not enough to determine an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** As @WDUK correctly states, the following answer is wrong. It would explain recursive in `loadView`, not `viewDidLoad`.

Old, wrong answer:

> Recursive calls occur when after the call to `-[super viewDidLoad]`
>   the view property has not been set and you then call `self.view`.
>
> You probably just forgot to connect the view to the file's owner's
>   view outlet.

Comment: Are you sure? This would occur in `loadView`, but not `viewDidLoad`, as (by definition of the method), `viewDidLoad` means the view property has already been loaded.

Comment: Thank you. That was the key.

Answer (score 0):

When the device runs out of available memory, it could dealloc the view if it is not currently visible. You should always make sure you handle this behaviour correctly.

I could happen when you for example switch to another view when using a navigation or tabbarcontroller.

Comment: That would not trigger *recursive* calls.

Comment: O I see, does the same behaviour occur when you run it outside of debugging (log and check the console) ?